# Re-branding an iOS Application (as compared to Android)

Tags: android, ios, resources

We purchased the source code to a certain Android and iOS application and now need to re-brand it before releasing it on the app stores.  I'm quite familiar with Android, so that side wasn't an issue.  However, I've never touched iOS apps before, so I have a few questions.

On the Android side, we changed the application name by changing several string resources.  Then we changed the package name in the manifest.xml file (to make this a unique application in the eyes of Google Play) along with changing the package names in the affected class files.  And compile.

Would iOS applications require something similar?  Is there an equivalent to the Android string resources where I can change strings in one place and they are reused throughout the application?  Also do iOS applications have some sort of unique ID, the equivalent of the Android's package name in the manifest.xml file?  If I change this unique ID, does it impact the code in any way (in Android the package name corresponds to the main application Java package that starts the application).

Comment: You can just change it in Project settings in Xcode. Much more convenient than in Android.

Comment: Under *most* circumstances, the application id is generated from the target name, which as Raptor points out, you can change in the Project settings.

Answer (score 0):

The package name you referred is called **Bundle Identifier** in iOS world.

It can be changed in Project settings, or directly in the project property list (.plist) in the Xcode project.

The original value may look like:

```
com.example.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

You can change it to whatever valid values you want (highly suggest you use reversed FQDN format).

Remember to clean & rebuild to project after changing this value, and all App ID, Provisioning Profiles and probably certificates have to be re-configured.